# Arrays and references in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Today I was reading article [What Reference Do](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) from PHP's official manual page and found the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1);
$a =& $arr[0]; //$a and $arr[0] are in the same reference set
$arr2 = $arr; //not an assignment-by-reference!
$arr2[0]++;
/* $a == 2, $arr == array(2) */
```

And that what manual says about this code:

> References inside arrays are potentially dangerous. Doing a normal
> (not by reference) assignment with a reference on the right side does
> not turn the left side into a reference, but references inside arrays
> are preserved in these normal assignments. This also applies to
> function calls where the array is passed by value.

Can someone explain me why after execution of the code we will have $a and $arr equal to 2 ?

Comment: Because 'references inside arrays are preserved in these normal assignments', no?

Comment: @dpk2442 the array should be copied on write, isn't it so?

Comment: @dpk2442, you are not right. Arrays copied by reference, but only for read only. When you start to change second reference to array - php creates new *real* copy of initial array

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will make it clearer:

```
$arr = array(1,1);
$a =& $arr[0]; //$a and $arr[0] are in the same reference set
$arr2 = $arr; //not an assignment-by-reference!
$arr2[0]++;
$arr2[1]++;
/* $a == 2, $arr == array(2) */
var_dump($arr);
//outputs array(2) { [0]=> &int(2) [1]=> int(1) }
```

The reason the value is incremented is because `the reference inside the array is preserved in the normal assignment`. `$arr2[0]`, `$arr[0]` and `$a` now all refer to the same value, even though `$arr2` is a copy of `$arr`. Note how `$arr2[1]++` does not increment `$arr[1]`.

Comment: I get it now. `$arr[0]` and `$arr2[0]` are in the same reference set even if `$arr` and `$arr2` aren't

Comment: @JanDvorak Yup. Somewhat counterintuitive, but it helps to remember that when you assign by reference the original member no longer holds a value, but a reference, which is what is then assigned. When you assign the entire array, the copy is identical, which means it also contains a reference to the same value in that position.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `var_dump($arr);` and you'll see the issue. `$arr[0]` will have an `&int type`.

- This means `$arr[0]` becomes a reference to a value.
- And the `$arr` array will actually have a reference as its first value.
- When you duplicate the array, the reference is carried over as the first element will keep being a reference and will still modify the referenced value.

**It's an array thing.** Seems really weird but once you understand it, it makes sense... as much as PHP makes sense :)

**PS**: This behavior is why `call_user_func_array()` can take an `array()` of references as it's argument and allows you to call functions that accept reference arguments.